# sudo not working (accidentally deleted libz.so.1)

Tags: linux, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a Redhat 7 system and accidentally deleted the libz.so.1 symbol link under /lib64

I thought I can relink it with the actual copy of libz.so.1.7 using sudo ln -s but found that sudo does not work without the libz.so.1. Now I am stuck. Very stupid mistake, any remedy? Thanks!

Comment: Can you do so with from Live ISO?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you turn back to you next *swish knife* `su` which should allow you run with root permission too, after which you can run `yum install zlib.i686`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use live CD to rescue the system. But it works.

I used a Red Hat installation CD to enter the rescue mode. Then I was able to use command line prompt to create a symbolic libz.so.1 to libz.so.1.2.7. Once I rebooted it, everything recovered.

Comment: I used a redhat installation cd to enter the rescue mode. Then I was able to use command line prompt to create a symbolic libz.so.1 to  libz.so.1.2.7. Once I rebooted it, everything recovered.